# What can you say about the thermal properties of ZnO when you have the phonon dispersion relationship diagram of ZnO?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

[image]

Source: http://wolf.ifj.edu.pl/phonondb/zno.htm

So what can you say about the thermal properties of ZnO when you have this diagram above and what do the labels means?

Comment: What does your textbook say about the heat capacity of insulators?